# Algebraic Structures as Set (System)

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \{f_i:i\in I\})$ be an algebraic structure (e.g. a group or a vectorspace). I wonder wether it is possible to somehow express the algebraic structure by set (system), like for instance a $\sigma$-algebra. In other words, I want to express the structures induced by $\{f_i:i\in I\}$ by a system of sets. Is this possible at all?

Comment: I am and that is why I asked this question. (note that $\sigma$-algebra$ was just an example). I was wondering wether it is possible to express **algebraic** structures as a system of sets.

Comment: To a set theorist, everything is a set. A function from $A$ to $B$ is a certain kind of subset of $A\times B$. (A function is it graph). A binary relation on $A$  (e.g. "$<$") is any subset of $A\times A.$  A binary operation on $A$ is a function from $A\times A$ to $A$..... Etc.

Comment: I don't think this question is well posed unless some specific types of operations with sets are proposed. Then we can evaluate how well they can accommodate algebraic objects.

Comment: Well...you could? each $f_i$ is a set of ordered pairs

Comment: Let's consider a relative simple algebraic structure: a group. A group is a set $X$ equipped with a function $\star:X\times X\longrightarrow X$ such that $(x\star y) \star z = x\star(y\star z)$; there exists an element $0\in X$ such that $x\star 0 = x$; and for every $x\in X$ there exists an element $x^{-1}\in X$ such that $x\star x^{-1} = 0$. Now I want to express this structure by a system of sets. As @user254665 said, everything can be expressed as a set (or a system of sets) so I am sure that it is possible to use sets to represent the group structure.

Comment: I am trying to do this now but I am stuck already at simple structure like a group. Eventually, I want to talk about an object $(\Omega, \mathcal V)$ where $\mathcal V$ is some set (or system) and gives $\Omega$ the structure of a group.
Then let $\mathcal R$ be another (system of) set(s) that represents another algebraic structure, e.g. a ring, so that $(\Omega, \mathcal R)$ becomes a ring. 
To make more clear what I am aming at: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space. Changing $\mathcal T$ changes the topology on $\Omega$. I basically want the same but with algebraic structures.